# Syntax error near unexpected token `}' in a Bash function with an if-then statement

Tags: bash, shell-script, function, parameter, control-flow

I stored the following script in a file and created an `alias` to that file in the user's `bashrc`, then sourced that `bashrc`:

```
#!/bin/bash
domain="$1" && test -z "$domain" && exit 2

environment() {
    read -sp "Please enter the app DB root password:" dbrootp_1 && echo
    read -sp "Please enter the app DB root password again:" dbrootp_2 && echo
    if [ "$dbrootp_1" != "$dbrootp_2" ]; then echo "Values unmatched. Please try again." && exit 2 fi

    read -sp "Please enter the app DB user password:" dbuserp_1 && echo
    read -sp "Please enter the app DB user password again:" dbuserp_2 && echo
    if [ "$dbuserp_1" != "$dbuserp_2" ]; then echo "Values unmatched. Please try again." && exit 2 fi
}
environment
```

When I run `alias domain` I get this output:

```
+ /user/nwsm/nwsm.sh x
/user/nwsm/nwsm.sh: line 12: syntax error near unexpected token `}'
user/nwsm/nwsm.sh: line 12: `}'
```

Why is the syntax error? I didn't recognize a syntax error. Do you? Maybe there is another problem.

I don't see any alien characters in Nano (nor in Visual Studio Code):

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I seem to have missed 2 semicolons (`;`) before the `fi` (the closure of the `if` statement).

These are the correct if-then statements:

```
if [ "$dbrootp_1" != "$dbrootp_2" ]; then echo "Values unmatched. Please try again." && exit 2; fi
if [ "$dbrootp_1" != "$dbrootp_2" ]; then echo "Values unmatched. Please try again." && exit 2; fi
```

Note each semicolon before the `fi`, near the end of each line.

If the Bash error in stderr was something like *"Expected a semicolon in lines 6 and 10"*, I might not publish the question and answer.

Seems writing a Bash if-then statement is slightly more verbose than say, in JavaScript.

Comment: +1 for finding the mistake. `fi` by itself would be a valid argument to any command, so the parser can't really see that you missed the semicolon. (Of course `fi` doesn't make sense for `exit` here, but the meaning of the commands isn't relevant at that phase and can't be known in general.)